# Cannot exit Santa Fe Springs?

Tags: wasteland-2

In California, in Santa Fe Spring, I have completed the quest involving killing the dogs and fixing the walls. After talking to the CO, I cannot exit the map, there is a locked door with which I cannot interact between myself and the world map exit. Is this a bug or did I miss something ?

Also next to the chopper there is a character called Adrian Gordon, I cannot reach him, is this normal as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a key in your inventory that was given to you, as a reward, for completing the quest to patch all the holes around the compound.

Right click on the key and select use on the gate to get it to open.

Comment: you are right, I was given a key and did not notice it. Please can you add the conditions to receive the key so I can validate your reply.

Comment: You are given the key by the CO after you have patched all holes and talked to him. He tells you to explore the area or something, so you are given clear instructions to leave Santa Fe Springs.

Comment: Ok updated comment